# RIA Services: Server process returns multiple entities but Client shows 1 entity duplicated

Tags: silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I am running into an issue where RIA Services returns 3 entities from the server (I have verified while debugging on the server process, and have verified via Fiddler that the service is in face returning  3 entities.

I am using MVVM so I am calling Load on the client side using a helper function that I borrowed from a Shawn Wildermuth sample: Here's that code:

```
    // Generic query handling
     protected void PerformQuery<T>(DomainContext dc, string name, EntityQuery<T> qry, EventHandler<EntityResultsArgs<T>> evt) where T : Entity
    {
        dc.Load<T>(qry,(r) =>
        {
            if (evt != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (r.HasError)
                    {
                        evt(this, new EntityResultsArgs<T>(r.Error));
                    }
                    else if (r.Entities.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        evt(this, new EntityResultsArgs<T>(r.Entities));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    evt(this, new EntityResultsArgs<T>(ex));
                }
            }
        }, null);
    }
```

EntityResultsArgs is a simple class that exposes an exception property (called Error) and a Results property (containing the results if we got any).

On the server we are mapping the result using AutoMapper to our exposed Domain Classes and this particular service call returns IEnumerable.

What am I missing (or what more would help someone figure this out).

Thanks!

Comment: Check your PK definition and make sure RIA services knows which column is unique.

Comment: BTW, when I set a break point on the "evt(this, new EntityResultsArgs<T>(r.Entities));" line I get 3 results all dups. If I set a break point on the RIA Services generated entity's name property I see all the data get set.. (but I end up with 3 dups instead of 3 distinct records)

Comment: Key attribute is set on the correct field

Comment: But I think you have the right idea.. Just had my co-worker (the service's author) check to make sure AutoMapper is properly setting the key.. not sure that it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, the problem is now confirmed. I was retrieving 3 entities back from the service all with an Id (aka the "[Key]" value) of 0.